# Keeping content above the bottom bar on Mobile Safari iOS 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I'm aware that minimal-ui is no longer supported on iOS8. But, I have some content fixed to the bottom of a webpage.

The page height is set to 100vh to take up the entire viewport. Some of the content at the bottom is displaying below the bottom bar. So, the user must scroll to see that content.

I would like all of the content to be displayed above the bottom bar. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to give a little more of padding-bottom to the element with 100vh in order to leave some space to the iphone bottom bar.

Just use this code to target the mobiles with Safari:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    _::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only {
        padding-bottom: 65px; //resize 
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add the **.safari_only** class to the element you want to target, example:

```
<div class='safari_only'> This div will have a padding-bottom:65px in a mobile with Safari  </div>
```

One detail: this is gonna affect also the Safari browser in Android devices, but fortunately not many users use Safari on an Android device, anyway if you need it you can use another css rule for overwrite that rule on Android.